# getAction() returns an empty array when upgraded to axios 0.24.0 from 0.19.0

Tags: redux, axios

I am trying to test my redux action creator.
When axios version was 0.19 it was working fine. But when upgraded to version 0.24.0
it returns empty array.

React version : 16.12.0

here is my code :

```
const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('Actions', () => {
  let store;
  let server;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore();
    store.clearActions();
    server = fakeServer.create({ respondImmediately: true });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    server.restore();
  });



    describe('for My api', () => {
    it('should dispatch successful _RESULTS_REQUEST_FULFILLED action', (done) => {
      const payload = JSON.stringify(myMock);
      const expectedAction = [
        {
          type: actionConstant.MY_RESULTS_REQUEST_FULFILLED,
          payload: myMock,
        },
      ];

      server.respondWith('GET', 'https://' + API_HOST_NAME + '/emp/api?&q=&start=0&sort=', [
        200,
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        payload,
      ]);

      setImmediate(() => {
        store
          .dispatch(actionCreators.getResults())
          .then(() => {
            expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedAction);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
        done();
      });
    });
```